# Active wait on previous block without atomicAdd(x,0)

Tags: cuda

I have a CUDA kernel where a blocks requires every previous blocks to be finished before the new block can be executed. I achieve this synchronization with two atomic counters like this:

```
__global__
static void waitTest(int* counters)
{
    __shared__ int orderedBlockId;
    int tid = threadIdx.x;

    if(tid == 0){
        orderedBlockId = atomicAdd(&counters[0], 1 );
        //wait on previous group of 16 blocks
        int expectedCounter = orderedBlockId / 16 * 16;
        while(atomicAdd(&counters[1],0) < expectedCounter){
            //wait
        }
    }
    __syncthreads();

    //do something

    __syncthreads();

    if(tid == 0){
        atomicAdd( &counters[1], 1 );
    }
}

int main(){
    thrust::device_vector<int> counters(2,0);
    waitTest<<<128,128>>>(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(counters.data()));
}
```

My question:

Is there a cheaper way of forcing a global memory read instead of `atomicAdd(&counters[1],0)`? 
Replacing it just with `counters[1]` time-outs the kernel.

Comment: mark `counters` as `volatile`

Comment: @RobertCrovella Then I get `no instance of overloaded function "atomicAdd" matches the argument list`

Comment: cast it to the non-volatile type when you use it in `atomicAdd`

Comment: Well thanks, that's it. I tried it with volatile before, but completely forgot that you can cast it away.

Comment: You can answer your own question if you want.  It may be useful for future readers to know what you did to fix it.

Comment: Isnt making a variable `volatile` only ensures that the data is read from the actual memory rather than the cache but doesnt ensure the data is read without a race condition? or is it safe to assume that int read/write is atomic?

Comment: An integer read without a write is always atomic. So you won't read 2 bytes of the old value and 2 bytes of the new value. `atomicAdd(&counters[1],0)` can be replaced safely with a `volatile` read because it always writes the same value as it reads and therefore the write can be removed.

Comment: but theres still `atomicAdd(&counters[1], 1)` operation which is a write, so while 0th thread of a one block reads that integer,  0th thread of some other block might write to it?

Comment: Yes, but what is the problem? Both operations are atomic.

Answer (score 1):

As Robert mentioned in the comments the `counters` have to be declared as `volatile`. In order to pass them to `atomicAdd` the counters have to be cast back to their original types (without `volatile`). Code:

```
__global__
static void waitTest(volatile int* counters)
{
    __shared__ int orderedBlockId;
    int tid = threadIdx.x;

    if(tid == 0){
        orderedBlockId = atomicAdd( (int*) &counters[0], 1 );
        //wait on previous group of 16 blocks
        int expectedCounter = orderedBlockId / 16 * 16;
        while(counters[1] < expectedCounter){
            //wait
        }
    }
    __syncthreads();

    //do something

    __syncthreads();

    if(tid == 0){
        atomicAdd( (int*) &counters[1], 1 );
    }
}
```

Comment: The idea of assigning a `orderedBlockId` for each block instead of using `blockId.x` straight away is to avoid a block with a higher block id using a sm before a lower block id which might cause unwanted stallings (worst case a deadlock). Is that right?

Comment: Exactly. There is no guarantee that blocks with low `blockId.x` are executed before blocks with high `blockId.x`.